# How is $ i^{-1} = -i$ and $i^{-3} = i$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Now I know that with positive powers of $i$ the cycle is:  $i , -1 , -i , 1\ldots$
The negative power cycle is: $-i , -1 ,  i , 1 \ldots$

Can someone explain to me how $\frac 1 {\sqrt{-1}}$ is equal to $-i$ and $\frac 1 {-\sqrt{-1}}$ is equal to $i$?

Comment: $$i\cdot =i^2=-1\implies i(-i)=1,$$ As $i^4=(i^2)^2=1,$ $$i^{-3}=i^4\cdot i^{-3}=i^{4-3}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee you could make that an answer... :)

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{-1}$ does not exist (not as a number anyway) hence the things you ask to explain are simply not true.

Comment: It's one thing to be pedantic and another to ignore obvious context, Did. You're simply being unhelpful.

Comment: @MichaelGrant If ever *learning* some mathematics interests you, please refer to my comments to EulCan's answer. You might also want to study how two other answers, perfectly clear and helpful and with zero pedantism in them, avoid carefully to mention at any moment the chimera $\sqrt{-1}$ (if you think this is happening by chance, you might want to think twice).

Comment: I've done so. Your little $z/w$ challenge fails rather simply. But sure, it's good that you can answer the question in a variety of ways, with and without $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Completely missing the point. Here is a thought experiment: what happens if the OP (justifiedly) *fails* an exam (that is, a math exam) because they followed your advice to use $\sqrt{-1}$, and consequently they lose a studies grant? Do you refund their grant then? (Gasp, suddenly real life enters the frame...)

Comment: @Did: why would they fail? If their professor considers $\sqrt{-1}$ such an offense that they would fail a student over it, then *it's the professor's fault* for failing to teach their student the conventions they expect them to follow in their own classroom. It is also a reflection of either the professor's own ignorance or arrogance that they would ignore the legitimate disagreement on this issue within the mathematical community. I would have pity on such a student for having such a lousy teacher.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Are you ready to take the engagement to refund them? ("Disagreement on this issue within the mathematical community": Which disagreement? There is no "disagreement" about this in the mathematical community, to think there is is delusional.)

Comment: @Did "No disagreement?" Oh for goodness' sake. I get that you hate its usage. But you're clearly smart enough to know that's not true. I am reluctant to accuse you of lying, so perhaps you're engaging in a No True Scotsman fallacy. In fact, incidences of the use of $\sqrt{-1}$ abound. Perhaps you need to take up your crusade with, say, [Paul Nahin](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9259.html) and his many endorsers, or [Barry Mazur](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/), just for a start. Indeed, as authors of *popular* work on the topic, they are the heretics you should attack first!

Comment: @Did Here's another person with [far more influence than me](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/imaginary_complex_precalc/i_precalc/v/i-as-the-principal-root-of--1--a-little-technical) corrupting millions of impressionable young minds; please hurry and correct him! And [Stephen Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sqrt%5B-1%5D): there's a mathematician with a big ego; someone needs to let him know his Alpha engine has it all wrong.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I see, Khan Academy and WA both use $\sqrt{-1}$, so that settles the matter. O my... More seriously, naturally authors of books put $\sqrt{-1}$ on their books' cover, if only for startling their potential readers (and they are right to). The question is: Do serious maths books/lecturers use it when they go to the heart of the matter for their readers/students? Re Mazur, you probably allude to "Imagining Numbers (Particularly the Square Root of Minus Fifteen)". Does it strike you as a book aimed at aspiring mathematicians? This is not exactly what the preface says... In ...

Comment: ... the end, people usually come to math.SE to get some rigor and rock-solid solutions to problems that confuse them. By sticking to the notation $\sqrt{-1}$, one may feel smart but one does exactly the opposite. (As an aside, I should feel thankful towards you for giving me the opportunity to dissect this misconception in detail for math.SE readers' benefit.)

Comment: @Did of course it doesn't settle the matter, though it does dispel the obviously false claim that "there is no disagreement about this in the mathematical community." I welcome your retraction that I am delusional. (Whew, I'm glad I didn't choose Wikipedia, you'd have really nailed me!) And no, nether Dr. Nahin nor Dr. Mazur limit their use of $\sqrt{-1}$ to the cover of the book. I welcome any excerpts you might wish to provide, in either text, that explains why "real" mathematicians never use the notation.

Comment: By the way, I am grateful to the mysterious person who has been upvoting some of my responses to Did. I understand why it might be unpleasant to wade into the skirmish oneself.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Because (for the n-th time) it is misleading. (And I do not know where you saw a retraction about the claim that "there is no disagreement about this in the mathematical community", actually the examples you provided support it.)

Comment: @Did my sarcasm didn't come through. But seriously, I cannot possibly see how you could claim my examples *support* your claim. In every case they make liberal use of the "faulty" notation. It's one thing to claim (as you did) that "popular" writing like that allows for certain license. But seriously, to suggest that these *support* your claim is, well, I won't use the same word.

Comment: $\sqrt{-1}$ is not well-defined. The square root function can be extended to the complex plane with an appropriate branch cut, but depending on the branch cut used, $\sqrt{-1}$ could be $i$, $-i$, or simply not defined (when the branch cut contains $-1$). Because of the lack of a conventional definition, it is better to use $i$ or $-i$, depending on which is intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part of your question, multiply the fraction by $\frac{i}{i}$ & observe that:
$$\frac{1}{i}=\frac{i}{i\cdot i}=\frac{i}{-1}=-i$$

For the second part of the question, observe that:
$$\frac{1}{-i}=-\frac{1}{i}$$

Then use the reasoning that that $\frac{1}{i}=-i$ from the part one. If I've misunderstood what you're asking, please feel free to tell me (with more brackets, so I can see what you want).

I've edited all traces of $\sqrt{-1}$ to $i$ in response to *Robjohn*'s comments. In future, it would be helpful if other users are less disrespectful when disagreeing with each other. Thanks.

Comment: @EulCan First, it is not true that one does not know what $\sqrt2$ is, it is *the unique real number $x$ such that $x^2=2$ and $x\geqslant0$. Second, in the complex field, there is no "positive" root anymore hence $\sqrt{-1}$ cannot be defined as *the unique complex number $z$ such that $z^2=-1$ and [suitable property]*. Hence using the notation does not convey the operations at all but can only confuse the reader (especially, anybody asking a question as the one on this page). Please do not choose to *maintain* a confusion in the OP's mind.

Comment: @Did I've looked up similar arguments for your case because, while still unconvinced, I'd like to make my case more rigorous & feel as though you're likely correct. Is there a definition of $i$ that would satisfy your point? Wikipedia gives the definition as $i^2=-1$ but this is also true for $-i$; you said yourself in question $677619$ that one can't define $i$ as $\sqrt{-1}$. I'm all in favour of technical correctness but still have doubts.

Answer (score 2):

$$i^{-1}=\frac1i=\frac i{i\cdot i}=\frac i{i^2}=\frac i{-1}=-i\quad\text{QED}$$
$$i^{-3}=\frac1{i^3}=\frac{i}{i^3\cdot i}=\frac{i}{i^4}=\frac{i}1=i\quad\text{QED}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}i=i^{-1}$ is true by definition and $n+\frac{1}n=\frac{n^2+1}n$ (since $n=\frac{n^2}n$ and $\frac{n^2}n+\frac{1}n=\frac{n^2+1}n$) is also true. If you plug $i$ in $\frac{i^2+1}i=\frac{-1+1}i=\frac{0}i=0$.
Therefore $i+\frac{1}i=0$ and $\frac{1}i=-i$. By our original statement (namely $i^{-1}=\frac{1}i$) we can conclude that $i^{-1}=-i$.

$i^{-3}=\frac{1}{i^{3}}$ by definition also and $n- \frac{1}{n^3}=\frac{n^4-1}{n^3}$ (since $\frac{n^4}{n^3}-\frac{1}{n^3}$ clearly is $\frac{n^4-1}{n^3}$) when we plug $i$ into this $\frac{i^4-1}i = \frac{1-1}{i} = \frac{0}i = 0$. 
Thus, $i - \frac{1}{i^3}$ = 0. This becomes $\frac{1}{i^3}=i$. Therefore $i^{-3} = i$.

Comment: It really helps readability to format using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Answer (score 0):

You know that $i^2 = -1$ (this is almost the definition of $i$, and anyway you've already written as much with your list of powers of $i$), and rearranging gives

$i(-i) = 1$,

so by definition $i^{-1} = -i$. Similarly, factoring the left-hand side of $i^4 = 1$ gives

$i(i^3) = 1$,

so

$i^{-3} = (i^3)^{-1} = i$.

Though it's not a proof, exactly, there's a useful way to think about multiplication by (powers of) $i$, and indeed, complex numbers in general. Multiplying any complex number $a + bi$ (which we can visualize as the point $(a, b)$ in the Cartesian plane) by $i$ gives

$i(a + bi) = ai + b i^2 = -b + ia$,

which we can visualize as the point $(-b, a)$. But this is exactly the point we get when we rotate our starting point $(a, b)$ anticlockwise about the origin a quarter-turn! (To see this, just note that $(a, b)$ and $(-b, a)$ are the same distance from the original, and the line segments connecting them are perpendicular; we can see the latter using the dot product or the fact that the slopes of the segments have product $-1$, provided our first point wasn't on a coordinate axis.)

So, multiplying by $i^2$ is rotates a point a quarter turn twice, for a total of a half-turn about the origin (or just reflects it through the origin if you like), multiplying by $i^3$ rotates a point three-quarters of a turn around the origin, and multiplying by $i^4$ rotates a point a full turn around the origin, but this is the same as not rotating the point at all. Since $i(-i) = 1$, multiplying by $-i = i^{-1}$ undoes the transformation given by multiplying by $i$, and so it must rotate points *clockwise* about the origin. With these facts in hand, both your useful sequences of powers of $i$ and the two identities you asked about become intuitive statements about rotating some multiple of quarter-turns.

If this sort of thing interests you, you might like to try to work out the geometric meaning of multiplying by a general complex number $c+di$. This generalizes further to quarternions, a number system that includes the complex numbers, as well as new directions parametrized by new constants $j$ and $k$, and which can be used to track rotations in three-dimensional space.